# import keyboard seg fault python Macos Big Sur

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, macos, segmentation-fault

I'm having a strange issue I've never experienced in python before. When I try to import the keyboard module: `import keyboard`, my program sends a segmentation fault. I have ran the program with sudo and without. Ive reinstalled the package, and it still won't work. Any help?

Also, very important to mention but I am on MacOS Big Sur. I believe the lack of permissions are the source of this issue, however I am unsure how to add them.

Code:

```
import keyboard
keyboard.press_and_release('space')
```

Error:

```
usr@MacBook-Air Program % python3 keystrokes.py 
zsh: segmentation fault  python3 keystrokes.py
```

Comment: I am also having this problem on Big Sur

Answer (score 1):

With MacOS you have to explicitly allow your terminal program to 'control' your computer.  In this case your terminal is controlling the keyboard.

Go to:
System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy Tab.
Then: Select the Accessibility and add your terminal program to the list.
In my case it was iTerm, yours may be different.

Note: I am using MacOS 12.5 (Monterey), but here is the link to Apple Support describing the process in more detail (Specifically for Big Sur)

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/allow-accessibility-apps-to-access-your-mac-mh43185/11.0/mac/11.0

Answer (score 0):

Might be a Mac compatibility issue as mentioned by Samuel, I'm on a M1 Mac and couldn't import it without getting a seg fault. I just moved over to using input() to wait for the user to press Enter as opposed to using the whole keyboard library. If you need more complicated functionality, pygame also has some great key_down and key press detection functionality.